# Can't install xfce4-mixer

Tags: debian, audio

When I go to Synaptic and try to install `xfce4-mixer` it responds:

```
xfce4-mixer:
 Depends: libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0 but it is not going to be installed
 Depends: libgstreamer0.10-0 but it is not going to be installed
 Depends: libkeybinder0 but it is not going to be installed
 Depends: libxfce4util6 but it is not going to be installed
  Depends: xfce4-panel (<4.11) but 4.12.0-4 is to be installed
 Depends: gstreamer0.10-alsa but it is not going to be installed or
    gstreamer0.10-audiosink
 Depends: gstreamer0.10-plugins-base but it is not going to be installed
 Recommends: gstreamer0.10-alsa but it is not going to be installed
```

I have Debian stretch (testing), do you know why I can't install this?

Answer (score 2):

`xfce4-mixer` wasn't included in the Stretch release or any subsequent release of Debian.

Stretch Xfce uses PulseAudio and `xfce4-pulseaudio-plugin` is available for the Xfce desktop — it can be added to Xfce panels.

Answer (score 0):

as you use a testing branch of debian, probably there is a dependency conflict and some packages could not be resolved and are not installed. You should wait some day to see if it will be resolved by upstream developers. If it will not be resolved in short time, you could try to fill a bug report.

***a more complete error log may be more useful***